# Spring JMS: Connection Factory for unknown provider

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-jms

Maybe it is a extreme newbie question, but:

I'm about to implement sending a message to a queue. The problem is, all I know is that it is a JMS Queue, but no idea, which implementation (it is just called ESB).

So now I have to have a connectionFactory bean, and all examples I saw use ActiveMqConnectionFactory. Is there any generic factory/implementation? JMS is a standard, so I should not be bound to some specific factory implementation, right?

Answer (score 0):

Correct. What you need is `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory` and `javax.jms.Destination`.
However, as you say it is ESB, there should some connection properties to the server, e.g. JNDI, or some service-locator to connect to the bus and call appropriate service.

Actually not enough info, what you have in hands regarding that ESB

Comment: But wait, javax.jms.ConnectionFactory is an interface... I need some concrete implementation...

Comment: Why? If you have an ESB it has to provide for you an implenetation, you just need to ask it to return a JMS connection factory. Your task just to work with contract, and you are a JMS client, not a server. Right, if your ESB server is ActiveMQ, you can use it's client to connect to the server. But for me it looks a bit odd: what is a reason of ESB, if your client application depends on concrete implementation.

Comment: There is no JNDI, so I cannot "load" it magically. So there is no such thing like "standard JMS connection factory"? (Like standard FTP client and so on)...

Comment: Which options to connect do you have?

Comment: I suppose I will just get an URL and the name of the Queue... Well, if it is a standard, should not the ActiveMQ client implementation handle it correctly too?

Comment: Not really: ActiveMQ client is really for ActiveMQ Broker. There is need to know which JMS implementation is on your ESB

Comment: That's the point - if it really is so, then I am disgusted with that quasi-standard... :( Thanks anyway for help